# Wordpress shortcode pagination

Tags: wordpress

I've created a shortcode for custom post with advanced custom fields. All works correctly except the pagination. I've tried all of the options I can see on other posts, but none work for me. Pagination is working on custom post pages.

```
function link_carstwo( $atts ) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'cartype' => 'porsche',
    'section' => 'make'
), $atts));
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );
$list = ' ';
echo '<div id="car-container">
  <ul id="carlist">';
//Setup the query to retrieve the posts that exist under each term


        global $post;
    $posts = new WP_Query (array(
          'post_type' => 'cars',
          'orderby' => 'menu_order',
          'order' =>  'ASC',
          $section => $cartype,
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'posts_per_page' => 9,
          'paged' => $paged,
          ));

        // Here's the second, nested foreach loop that cycles through the posts associated with this category
        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) { $posts->the_post();
         ////set up post data for use in the loop (enables the_title(), etc without specifying a post ID--as referenced in the stackoverflow link above)
$price = get_field('price', $post->ID);
$car_image = get_field('car_image', $post->ID);
$image_position = get_field('image_position', $post->ID);
$make = get_field('make', $post->ID);
$year = get_field('year', $post->ID);
$date_purchased = get_field('date_purchased', $post->ID);
$finance_type = get_field('finance_type', $post->ID);
$job_title = get_field('job_title', $post->ID);
$model = get_field('model', $post->ID);

$list .=  '<li class="carbox"> 
<p>TEST</p>
<div class="image2"  style="background-image:url(' . $car_image .');background-position: ' . $image_position . ' center;"></div>
<p class="car"> '.$make.' ' . $model . ' ' . $year . ' </br> £ ' . $price . '        ' . $date_purchased . '</p>
<p class="finance">' . $finance_type . '</p>
<p class="fademeSmall"> ' . $job_title . '</p>
<p class="linked"><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) .'" class="orangeButtonRound"></a></p>
</li>';

        } 
'</ul></div>';


return 


 '<div class="navigation centerWidth">' 
 . $list 
 .the_posts_pagination( array(
 'mid_size'  => 2,
 'prev_text' => __( '<', 'textdomain' ),
 'next_text' => __( '>', 'textdomain' ),
 ) ) 
 . '<div class="nav-previous">' . get_next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts' ) ) . '</div>'
 . '<div class="nav-next">' . get_previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ) ) . '</div>'
 . 'TEST</div>' .
 wp_reset_query();
 }



add_shortcode( 'car-gridtwo', 'link_carstwo' );
```

Comment: So is it showing all the cars at once or is it paging and just not showing the next/prev controls or is it something else?

Comment: Hi, it's showing the cars, just not the pagination. If I look in the generated code the divs are there, but not being populated, as if there are no more cars, but there are more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your pagination

```
            <?php
        global $wp_query;

        $big = 999999999; 
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
            ) );

            ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, could I be missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using wp_query and the global variables is extremely convoluted and wrong.

```
while ( $post->have_posts() ) { $posts->the_post();
```

On the while condition you should have **$posts**->have_posts() rather than **$post**->have_posts()

You also don't need the  `setup_postdata($post);`

I'm not sure that this will solve the issue, everything else seems "fine" to me.

**EDIT**

Having a closer look at the code I just noticed that your return statement is within the loop, that's wrong and might be the reason why you are having the pagination issue. Just close the While block before the return statement (and obviously remove the last closing bracket, before `wp_reset_query`). Don't forget to do the change I suggested before as well.

Comment: I've also tried using foreach($posts as $post) :, which still works, but still no pagination

Comment: Check my update on this answer and let me know if it solves the issue.

Comment: Still no luck. It's returning the div, just no pagination. I've also tried the_posts_pagination

Comment: Can you update your question with the most updated code? Might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I've done this now, so hopefully you can see if I'm still getting it wrong! I've used two different pagination templates just to see if either gets returned but they don't